# use the __set and __get magic methods to instantiate classes

Tags: php

I am autoloading my classes and want a way to dynamically instantiate the class when used.

Instead of having 20 class instantiations in my parent class, I want a way to instantiate a class when its being called.

for example:

```
$this->template->render();
```

will instantiate

```
$this->template = new Template();
```

I attempted this

```
public function __set($name, $value)
{
    return $this->$name;
}

public function __get($name)
{
    $this->$name = new $name();
}
```

This doesn't seem to work, but I also think I'm doing it wrong.

One issue that I can't figure out also is that my classes reside in the \System namespace. I can't seem to tack on `new "\System".$name()` or `new \System.$name()` without getting an error;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private $_template;
public function __set($name, $value)
{
  $this->{'_' . $name} = $value;
}

public function __get($name)
{
  if (!$this->{'_' . $name}) {
    $classname = '\\System\\' . ucfirst($name);
    $this->{'_' . $name} = new $classname();
  }
  return $this->{'_' . $name};
}
```

Comment: is there a way to automatically create properties much how you can create a property in the __construct() method?

Comment: You already want to name your "virtual" property `template`, thus it's not wise to name the real one the same.

Comment: Shouldn't the `__set()` method be setting something instead of returning something?

Answer (score 3):

[__get](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) needs to return a value. as such:

```
public function __get($name)
{
    $this->$name = new $name();
    return $this->$name;
}
```

is one part of the puzzle.

From what you've said you don't need __set at all - unless the equivalent property is declared as protected and you're going to set it from outside the instance (but why would you do that).

As indicated by @KingCrunch, you can reference a namespaced class as:

```
$classname = '\\System\\' . ucfirst($name);
$foo = new $classname;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking more for this:

```
public function __set($name, $value)
{
    $this->$name = $value;
}

public function __get($name)
{
    if (isset($this->$name)) {
        return $this->$name;
    }

    $class = sprintf('\\System%s', ucfirst($name));
    return $this->$name = new $class();        
}
```

it takes care of the classname and that the assignment is actually made (which was missing in your code).